# How to get next month and previous month from String (Month and Year)

Tags: java, android

When click on next button i need to set the next month to text view without opening the month picker and similarly to previous button also. Please can any one help me.

Here is my code

```
Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();//getting date
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-YYYY");
    String date = formatter.format(today);
    Calendar today1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    textView.setText(date);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {
                String dateString = textView.getText().toString();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-YYYY");
                //Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you use `java.time`?

Comment: You should be using java.time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get month,year from `Calender` as String , then parse it as `LocalDate` then format it through formater .

Example-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView monthView;
Button next, previous;
public static LocalDate localDate;
private String dateFormat;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    monthView = findViewById(R.id.tvLDate);
    next = findViewById(R.id.next);
    previous = findViewById(R.id.previous);


    getDate();

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            localDate = localDate.plusMonths(1);
            monthView.setText(monthFormat(localDate));

        }
    });
    previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            localDate = localDate.minusMonths(1);
            monthView.setText(monthFormat(localDate));
        }
    });



}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void getDate() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String month = calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
    String year = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    dateFormat = "01/" + month + "/" + year;
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MMMM/yyyy");
    localDate = LocalDate.parse(dateFormat, formatter);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private String monthFormat(LocalDate date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM");
    return date.format(formatter);
}
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to show year also with month? Then use pattern  "MMMM yyyy" in dateformat() method.

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is ->

// Get an instance of calendar and set the required Date()

```
 val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()      
    mButtonNextMonth.setOnClickListener {
     calendar[Calendar.MONTH] += 1 // This will give you the currently selected month +1
    }
    mButtonNextMonth.setOnClickListener {
     calendar[Calendar.MONTH] -= 1 // This will give you the currently selected month -1
    }
```